# XSLT copying AS IS

Tags: xslt, copying

i have xml i want to copy as is like (check xmlns="" and  tags. i want to create as is . the total calculation is taken care. only this issue . it is valid . still client want the expected format to be like that. any help greatly appreciated.

source.xml

```
       <Employees>
       <employee>
        <dept>1</dept>
        <sec></sec>
         <employee>
          <employee>
           <dept>2</dept>
               <sec></sec>
            <employee>
            </Employees>
```

Expectedresult.xml

```
                  <Employees xmnls="1.2" xmlns:xsi="3" xsi:schemalocation="4">
                    <totalemp>2</totalemp>
                   <employee>
                     <dept>1</dept>
                      <sec></sec>
                     <employee>
                      <employee>
                           <dept>2</dept>
                                  <sec></sec>
                         <employee>
                        </Employees>
```

Actual result

```
                         <Employees>
                              <totalemp>2</totalemp>
                               <employee xmlns="">
                                <dept>1</dept>
                                  <sec/>
                                </employee>
                                 <employee>
                                   <dept>2</dept>
                                      <sec/>
                                   <employee>
                                  </Employees>
```

Comment: w/o seeing your XSLT, it is impossible to know what you did to cause this. Also, which XSLT engine?

Comment: Tell your client to get a real XML parser

Comment: Your input isn't well formed XML, so I fail to see how you can get any output at all.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get `<sec/>` to output like `<sec></sec>`, try adding `method="html"` to your `xsl:output` (if you have one?).

Example:

**XML Input** (well-formed):

```
<Employees>
  <employee>
    <dept>1</dept>
    <sec/>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <dept>2</dept>
    <sec/>
  </employee>
</Employees>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="html"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Employees">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <totalemp><xsl:value-of select="count(employee)"/></totalemp>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output** (tested with Xalan and Saxon 6.5.5)

```
<Employees>
   <totalemp>2</totalemp>
   <employee>
      <dept>1</dept>
      <sec></sec>
   </employee>
   <employee>
      <dept>2</dept>
      <sec></sec>
   </employee>
</Employees>
```

Comment: do you any other option my result file should be xml iam using biztalk in the pipeline i call this xslt file in the send port

Comment: Iam getting Xmlns="", i want to get rid of it