# Xslt Blank Namespace

Tags: xslt, namespaces

i have xml i want to copy as is like (check xmlns="" and tags. i want to create as is . the total calculation is taken care. only this issue . it is valid . still client want the expected format to be like that. any help greatly appreciated.

```
        **Input.xml**

 <Employees>
   <employee>
    <dept>1</dept>
    <sec></sec>
     </employee>
      <employee>
       <dept>2</dept>
           <sec></sec>
        </employee>
        </Employees>
```

Expected

```
     <Employees xmnls="1.2" xmlns:xsi="3" xsi:schemalocation="4">
                <totalemp>2</totalemp>
               <employee>
                 <dept>1</dept>
                  <sec></sec>
                 <employee>
                  <employee>
                       <dept>2</dept>
                              <sec></sec>
                     <employee>
                    </Employees>
```

Actual

```
                        <Employees>
                          <totalemp>2</totalemp>
                           <employee xmlns="">
                            <dept>1</dept>
                              <sec/>
                            </employee>
                             <employee>
                               <dept>2</dept>
                                  <sec/>
                               <employee>
                              </Employees>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT copying AS IS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559129/xslt-copying-as-is)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have misunderstood your requirement, you can just match the **Employees** element, and output a new element with the required namespaces added. You will also need to match other elements, and specify the default namespace on them to avoid the `xmlns=''` appearing.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="1.2">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Employees">
      <Employees xmlns="1.2" xmlns:xsi="3" xsi:schemalocation="4">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
         <totalemp>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(employee)"/>
         </totalemp>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </Employees>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output:

```
<Employees xmnls="1.2" xsi:schemalocation="4" xmlns:xsi="3">
   <totalemp>2</totalemp>
   <employee>
      <dept>1</dept>
      <sec/>
   </employee>
   <employee>
      <dept>2</dept>
      <sec/>
   </employee>
</Employees>
```

Comment: Iam still geting Xmlns="" in the destination

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I have a typo in my XSLT which meant it didn't work correctly. I have corrected this now.

Comment: looking to to generate <sec></sec> i tried method=html still result is same

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear that was a requirement in your question. I thought it was just about the blank namespace. <sec></sec> is semanitcally the same as <sec/>. Are you sure this is actually required?

Comment: i know both are same. but the client wants <sec></sec> in that way.thanks for your help so far